# PHP session handler - current working directory changes before writing session data

Tags: php, session, working-directory

I'm using the `session_set_save_handler()` function to save the session to a database, I also have an autoloader that relies on the working directory being set to the application directory i.e. `chdir('C:\Some\App\Directory')`.

When the session is being written the working directory has changed to my php installation directory i.e. `C:\PHP`. This causes the autoloader to fatally error when it tries to require classes related to database persistence. Is there anyway round this?

I am using Zend Framework 1 and Doctrine 2 although I believe this to be a general PHP issue rather than with the libraries themselves.

Comment: if a call session_write_close() before exiting then there doesn't seem to be a problem. but this doesn't seem like a tidy solution

Comment: You are experiencing what is common with shutdown functions and PHP, see the warnings at http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php,  http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up just make the the paths for the autoloader absolute